# Why does CoffeeScript compile a for loop in this way?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This piece of CoffeeScript:

```
for i in [1..10]
  console.log i
```

is compiled to:

```
for (i = _i = 1; _i <= 10; i = ++_i) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't just use an `i`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with CoffeeScript, but my guess is that it is to prevent modification of the `i` variable within the loop.

For instance:

```
for i in [1..10]
  console.log i
  i = 7
```

might have produced this code

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
  console.log(i);
  i = 7;
}
```

This obviously produces an infinite loop.

CoffeeScript's version, however, means this happens:

```
for (i = _i = 1; _i <= 10; i = ++_i) {
  console.log(i);
  i = 7;
}
```

The loop is no longer infinite because of the presence of `_i` to track the position in the loop.